# Using conditions with IF statement to change arrays to pick a fastener

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have an input table where the user inputs the diameter and desired repair fastener type for each hole.  The last column should return the repair fastener for the correct diameter hole.  I have one table for fastener type "Solid" and one for "IFF."  I was able to get a formula written to call the correct solid fastener from the solid table.  I want to use an IF statement to be able to pick which fastener table to pull from, since some of the diameter tolerances overlap.

In the table below, the formula in the fastener column only works with the Solid table.  I want to use the input in the rep type column to control which table (Solid or IFF) the formula uses.  I tried with an IF statement, but the entire formula was bracketed and only returned A.  I tried something like =IF([rep type]="Solid", (pull the Solid fastener),IF([rep type]="IFF", (pull the IFF fastener)).  The 'pull' code is
`=INDEX(tbl_Solid[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_Solid[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[max])),ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[min])),1))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the IF function in Excel is `=IF(condition, formula for true case, formula for false case)`

You should be able to just do `=IF([@[rep type]]="Solid", (pull the Solid fastener),(pull the IFF fastener))`.  This would assume anything not "Solid" is "IFF"

If you want to do extra validation and have it only accept Solid/IFF, you can do `=IF([@[rep type]]="Solid", (pull the Solid fastener),IF([@[rep type]]="IFF", (pull the IFF fastener),""))`

Comment: when I enter in the formulas below, there's no change in results.  It doesn't seem to even look at the IFF table and I don't know how to fix that.

`=IF([rep type]="Solid",INDEX(tbl_Solid[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_Solid[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[max])),ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[min])),1)),IF([rep type]="IFF",INDEX(tbl_IFF[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_IFF[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[max])),ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[min])),1))))`

Comment: Your pull function's not working for me.  I think your ROW function is supposed to be treating it as an array, but it's not doing that here.  Try this: `=IF([rep type]="Solid",LOOKUP(2,1 / (([@diameter] >= tbl_Solid[[#All],[min]]) * ([@diameter] <=tbl_Solid[[#All],[max]])),tbl_Solid[[#All],[Fastener]]),IF([rep type]="IFF",LOOKUP(2,1 / (([@diameter] >= tbl_IFF[[#All],[min]]) * ([@diameter] <=tbl_IFF[[#All],[max]])),tbl_IFF[[#All],[Fastener]])))`.  Note it returns some #N/A errors because your sample includes values not in any range.

Comment: If the incoming hole diameter is not in a diameter tolerance, then I want the next size up fastener returned.

Comment: I wasn't using an array formula, if I do your pull function works. Your condition doesn't need to use the array, so you can change it to `=IF([@[rep type]]="Solid",INDEX(tbl_Solid[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_Solid[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[max])),ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[min])),1)),IF([@[rep type]]="IFF",INDEX(tbl_IFF[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_IFF[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[max])),ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[min])),1))))`

Comment: It took me awhile to find the difference.  What does the '@' do in the formula that made it work?

Comment: It uses the rep_type for the row you’re on instead of an array for all the rep_type entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365 with `XLOOKUP`, you can use:

```
=XLOOKUP([@diameter], CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid[max],IFF[max]),CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid[Fastener],IFF[Fastener]),,1)
```

or, a little shorter with the `LET` function:

```
=LET(x,CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid,IFF),XLOOKUP([@diameter],INDEX(x,0,2),INDEX(x,0,4),,1,1))
```

[image]

If you have an earlier version, try:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid,IFF),0,4),
     IFERROR(MATCH(1,([@diameter]>=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid,IFF),0,1))*
                     ([@diameter]<INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid,IFF),0,2)),0),
             1+MATCH(1,([@diameter]>=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid,IFF),0,1))*
             ([@diameter]<OFFSET(INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH([@[rep typ]],{"Solid","IFF"},0),Solid,IFF),0,2),1,0)),0)))
```

Comment: I really wish I had O365, but I do not.

Comment: @Piseagan This can be done in `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010+). Is that an option for you?

Comment: @Piseagan See my edit for a formula that should work in earlier versions of Excel, although I still think Power Query would be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I don't know what Power Query is.  I'll have to do some research on it.